Word for when baby is blowing raspberries (drooling, spit up)
I'm looking for a word for when a baby blows raspberries or spit bubble. For some reason, the word "babble" comes to mind, but I'm more look for the word when a baby (or anyone for that matter) drools and blows raspberries.
Here's an article on this phenomenom, that is mostly aimed at reassuing parents that it's normal:
https://www.webmd.com/baby/why-does-a-baby-blow-raspberries

A common usage is the baby gurgled

Any reason you reject drooling? It's in your question.

Other than 'blowing' can you say say which end of your baby the raspberries come from?
Beyond that how could 'drooling' equate to 'blowing (anything)' and how could even 'spitting up' either be a single word, or equate to 'blowing raspberries'?
My suggestion is that you withdraw the Question until you've given it a great deal more thought, and the choice remains yours.
